# Navigate to modal on tree grid

Tags: modal

I'm trying to create a URL on each of these items where clicking on it pops up a modal. Is this possible in Salesforce?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

you need to define it as url column and then define url as below & build nested data to have accountId:

```
    {
            type: 'url',
            fieldName: 'accountId',
            label: 'Account Name',
            typeAttributes: {
                label: { fieldName: 'Name' }
            }
        },
```

reference url: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:treeGrid/example#lightningcomponentdemo:exampleTreeGridAsyncExpand

Comment: It's only one nested item. Not sure what `typeAttributes` is doing in your example.

When I click Acme Corporation (Bay Area), how do I get it to pop up a modal?